# truffle migrate: calling method at the time of deployment

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, erc20

I am trying to initialize some contracts at the time of deployment using 'truffle migrate'.

Basically I want to create some user roles when my contracts gets deployed as one time task.

I am not sure how to do it, as during 'truffle migrate' when we call deployer.deploy(ContractA). The function returns the contract address as Promise.

Please help.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Are you saying you need to include role information at deployment time or you need the address after deployment so you can store role information for tthe contract in some other system?

Comment: I want to save some predefined roles at deployment time as new contract instances.